# Magento2 quote item row total rounding issue

Tags: magento2, quote, quoteitem, magento2-enterprise, sharedcatalog

We are facing issue in quote_item table with row_total column in which its not rounding prices of items. for example please check below screenshot:

[image: issue]

14.2250 should be 14.23

15.9750 should be 15.98

We are using the Magento Commerce Enterprise edition. and this thing happens especially when we set item prices to shared catalogs and add those items to the cart. in general, add to cart case, this doesn't happen.

Can anyone help what could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the default declarative database schema setting. You can see this, for example, in the file that describes the table you specified.

```
MAGENTO_ROOT/vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/db_schema.xml
```

**column parametrs**

```
<column xsi:type="decimal" name="row_total" scale="4" precision="20" unsigned="false" nullable="false"
        default="0" comment="Row Total"/>
```

Here you need to pay attention to the ***scale*** parameter, it indicates the number of digits after the decimal point.

About what each of the parameters means, as well as a way to override the default ones, you can find in the official guide. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html

Comment: do you mean change the precision of column? there are other columns that have same precision and no issue with it.

Comment: @bhargavshastri 
Sorry, maybe my English is not very good. But scale is not precision, it's a decimal point. Take a close look at the field configuration from my answer, the precision parameter is also there, but it is not the number of decimal places, and in this case the precision is 20 characters. Perhaps you could describe in more detail and specifically with which fields you have difficulties, and with which everything suits you. So I would probably better understand the whole essence of the issue.
`scale="4" precision="20"`, 
edit scale if I understand the problem correctly